# Transforming a generic $ARIMA(p,d,q)$ process to make it stationary

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, vector-autoregression

I am trying to build a VAR model with 6 variables. In addition to performing the ADF and KPSS tests for stationarity, I thought it might be interesting to use the [`auto_arima`](https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html#pmdarima.arima.auto_arima) functionality of the python package `pmd_arima` to see what types of time series the algorithm thinks are in play here. For the purposes of this question I will assume that the series are not cointegrated.

4 of the 6 variables turned out to simply be $I(1)$, which is great: this means that I can simply difference them before putting them in my VAR. But 2 times series exhibited more complex behaviour: one turned out to best be described by an $ARIMA(1, 0, 3)$ model, and another by an $ARIMA(0, 1, 2)$ model: what is the optimal way to go about making these stationary for the purposes of using them in a VAR model? Specifically I would like to avoid "simply" differencing them and thereby potentially destroying important information.

Asked another way, is there an algorithm whereby one can transform a generic $ARIMA(p, d, q)$ process to make it stationary?

Comment: According to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47495/whats-a-stationary-var, you should better ask if your variables are cointegrated!

Comment: Look into 1) error corrected models (as kjetil suggested), 2) fractional differencing